# Rolling for 720minutes on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

I Have a dataset as shown below. The idea is looking at every previous 720 minutes not the frequency which we use in grouper function. I want to see the number of positive changes in the previous 720 minutes. It doesn't really count the sum of positives for 720minutes.

```
row      Timestamp     Direction     Positive      Neg        Nut

 1    1/20/19 12:15    
 2    1/20/19 12:17    Nut
 3    1/20/19 12:17    Neg
 4    1/20/19 12:18    Neg
 5    1/20/19 12:19    Pos
 6    1/20/19 12:20    Neg
 7    1/20/19 12:21    Neg
 8    1/20/19 12:22    Pos
 9    1/20/19 12:23    Neg
 10   1/20/19 12:24    Pos
 11   1/20/19 12:25    Neg
 12   1/20/19 12:26    Neg
 13   1/20/19 12:27    Neg
 14   1/20/19 12:29    Neg
 15   1/20/19 12:29    Nut
 720   1/20/19 12:30   Pos           230(o2:o720)    284       205
 721   1/20/19 12:31   Nut           230(o3:o721)    284       206
```

So i am doing `=COUNTIF(Direction2:Direction721,"Pos")` in excel to calculate the Positive column. The code i tried work for 60minutes and 15minutes but when i use 720 minutes which is 12hours, i don't get the positive, neg counts as i wanted. It gives me a count of 0, 1 and so on, which is completely wrong.

Code tried:

```
cols = df['ChangeDirection'].dropna().unique()
for c in cols:
    df[c] = df['ChangeDirection'].eq(c).rolling('720min').sum()
df.loc[:df.index[0] + pd.Timedelta(720*60, unit="s"), cols] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i just realized i had a time gaps and it though works fine.